# Rails validate only the param keys passed into the update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm aware of rails conditional validations. However, I wanted to know if there's an easy way to just say: "If the field was included in the params hash passed in to the `update` method, validate it. Otherwise, don't bother."

For example, let's say I have a person with a `name` and an `age`, both of which are required fields. And let's say I do `p.update({name: 'Bob'})`. Then, I'm trying to update the name only. I don't want it to bother running the validation on the age field (if it does, the save will fail - but I'm not concerned about age at this point).

I realise I can use conditional validations to get this effect on a case-by-case kinda basis. But is there a more generic way? I would have thought only validating the attributes passed in to `update` would have been a common requirement... am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You say that you know about conditional validations, so I assume you mean that you know that you can do the following but don't find it acceptable:

```
validates :age ... , if: :age_changed?
```

AFAIK there is no other "more generic" way of getting at what you're after. But in answer to your final question, I think you're thinking about this the wrong way. Validations are built around the idea of asserting things about a model's state, not *changes changes made to its state*. It's a subtle difference but it's really at the crux of what you're dealing with.

I gather that what you were hoping for is something like:

```
p.update({ name: 'Bob'}, validate_only_changed_attributes: true) # not real
```

... but consider that (1) validations may be constructed from functions that depend on multiple attributes or no attributes at all, and (2) your model may contain "virtual attributes" that don't map in any straightforward way to database attributes. So in practice it would be difficult to constrain an arbitrary set of validations in the way you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, those are all valid points. Someone on twitter suggested a solution I'm happy with - I've put it in an answer below.

Comment: Nice. I assume you've seen [this](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services). I'm still curious about how you'd handle validations.

Comment: Hadn't seen that - thanks. If you watch the railscast, validations are actually super easy - I'll post in some example code in my answer.

Comment: Likewise if you use the reform gem, validations are easy with that, too - very similar to doing them in your model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly say for each attribute you're validating whether it's acceptable to allow nil:

```
validates :age, numericality: { only_integer: true }, allow_nil: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution on twitter that I'm happy with - not an answer to my question per se, but a better architecture:

"I'd suggest using dedicated form/service classes with just the validations you need." - https://twitter.com/joshuapaling/status/538169606876057600

There's a great railscast on form objects: http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects (and one on service objects http://railscasts.com/episodes/398-service-objects).

There's also the reform gem - https://github.com/apotonick/reform which looks nice, though I decided not to go with it for this time.

In case you're not subscribed to railscast (go subscribe! It's SOOO worth it, and only a single $9 charge, indefinitely, while Ryan Bates is on break), here's some example code, taken from the RailsCasts episode:

```
class SignupForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  # ^ do this and validations and stuff mostly just work - see lines below

  validates_presence_of :username
  validate :verify_unique_username
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6

  delegate :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, to: :user
  delegate :twitter_name, :github_name, :bio, to: :profile

  def user
    @user ||= User.new
  end

  def profile
    @profile ||= user.build_profile
  end

  def submit(params)
    user.attributes = params.slice(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    profile.attributes = params.slice(:twitter_name, :github_name, :bio)
    self.subscribed = params[:subscribed]
    if valid?
      generate_token
      user.save!
      profile.save!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def subscribed
    user.subscribed_at
  end

  def subscribed=(checkbox)
    user.subscribed_at = Time.zone.now if checkbox == "1"
  end

  def generate_token
    begin
      user.token = SecureRandom.hex
    end while User.exists?(token: user.token)
  end

  def verify_unique_username
    if User.exists? username: username
      errors.add :username, "has already been taken"
    end
  end
end
```